# jQuery issue with identical call when triggered from tab and button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a MVC page with jQuery-ui tabs. When user selects relevant tab a jQuery ajax call is executed to load a select list. It works fine. User can then reload the list by clicking a button to perform the same call once again.

When called from button the ajax call always fails!! I tried to swap order and skip the call on tab display, in order to make the button load be the first event. But it still gave the same error.

The ajax call is isolated in the same function being called. How can that be different when called from different events?

This is the related code:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    show: function (event, ui) {
        var tabName = $(ui.tab).attr("href");
        if (tabName == "#tabResult")
            loadResults();
    }
});


$("#btnLoadResults").click(function () {
    loadResults();
});


function loadResults() {
    var testCaseId = $("#TestCase_Id").val();
    $.getJSON("api/TestsApi/GetResults", { testCaseId: testCaseId })
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#lstResults").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    $("#lstResults").append("<option value='" + item.Id + "' data-response='" + item.Response + "'>" + item.StartTime + "</option>");
                });
                $("#txtResult").val("");
                $("#lstResults").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
            });
}
```

The call from tab show always works. The call from button click works when executed in debug environment, but not when deployed on intranet.

I checked in Fiddler but both calls are identical in request and response.

The resulting querystring looks very weird, like if the whole current form somehow is submitted ....

I noticed that jQuery-ui states that tab show event is "deprecated" and "activate" is to be used now. I tried activate but it does not work. My versions are jquery-ui-1.8.24.js and jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes my feedback to this issue.

It turns out that the whole problem was the missing type attribute of the button. The default behaviour turned out to be different in different browsers. In Internet Explorer the default is type="submit". When running on local machine this somehow was fine, but on remote machine it did not work. I have now specified type="button" and everything is fine again!

I also found out that the jQuery-ui tab event has changed name from version 1.8 to 1.9. In 1.8 it is "show" and in 1.9 and onwards it is "activate".